# Creating many objects using django-polymorphic

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm using [django-polymorphic](https://github.com/chrisglass/django_polymorphic) and have a base class with about 8 derived classes. It works great except when I try to create many objects at once, in this case the performance is very poor. My code looks like this:

```
class Parent(PolymorphicModel):
  ...
class DerivedA(Parent):
  ...
class DerivedB(Parent):
  ...

@transaction.commit_on_success
def create_objects()
  for model_class in (DerivedA, DerivedB...):
    instance = model_class(...)
    instance.save()
```

I've also tried using `Parent.objects.bulk_create`, but this doesn't work well with polymorphic-django, because it just creates the base object and not the child objects. When I try to use `bulk_create` of each of the child models, it raises `ValueError("Can't bulk create an inherited model")`.

Is there a more efficient way of creating many polymorphic objects?

Answer (score -1):

This was implemented in django admin

```
models.py

class BuildScript(models.Model):
   fields ...bla bla

class POLY_BuildScript(BuildScript):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "POLY"
    fields...bla bla

admin.py

#just after the imports (func stands alone)
def save_with_parent_fields(obj):
    obj.build = obj.pbuild
    obj.branch = obj.pbranch
    return obj

class BuildScriptAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.executer = request.user.userprofile
        obj.save()

class POLY_BuildScriptAdmin(BuildScriptAdmin):    
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        save_with_parent_fields(obj)
        obj.executer = request.user.userprofile
        obj.save()
```

the return obj from func is used elsewhere :)
enjoy